# Bitwise or-ing enums using generics

Tags: c#, generics, enums

It's possible to bitwise or enums. Typically this is done on [Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c) enums.

Eg `var foo = MyEnum.ABC | MyEnum.XCN`

I have tried to create a method convert an array of enums into a combined enum using generics.

Here is what I have tried:

```
private T CombineFlags<T>(params T[] flags) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return flags.Select(flag => flag).Aggregate((x, y) => x | y);
}
```

However, I can't apply operator '\' to T and T. Casting doesn't seem to help. `struct, IConvertible` seem to be the closest I can get to enums, but obviously not close enough to use the '|' operator. System.Enum also isn't very helpful.

How can I perform this operation on the generic enum? (Is it possible?)

Comment: you can't - operators are static and the compiler can't guess what T's are passed in - they might not support the `|` operator.

Comment: one thing you could try is convert the values to a `long`, do the operation and convert it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to apply a generic constraint on a type that that type be an `Enum`, or to apply a constraint that the type overloads the `|` operator, so anything that you do, by necessity, won't be able to maintain entirely static typing.

What you can do is change the enum to its underlying integer type, do the aggregation, and then cast it back.  The problem is that you can't (easily) solve is dynamically determining the underlying type and performing the bitwise or on that type (again due to a lack of constraints on a type having an overload of the `|` operator).  If you can assume that the underlying type of the enum is an `int` (or any smaller type) then you can do it, but if the underlying type of the enum is say a `long` then this code would break.  There's also the fact that non-enum values can be used for `T`, and those types may or may not function properly when passed to this method.

```
private static T CombineFlags<T>(params T[] flags) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    int n = flags.Select(flag => Convert.ToInt32(flag))
        .Aggregate((x, y) => x | y);
    return (T)(object)n;
}
```

Comment: a long might be safer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a static helper method to generate the needed `Or` function for your aggregate.  The function is generated on first access and cached for additional uses.

This assumes that the type passed will be an enum.

```
public T CombineFlags<T>(params T[] flags)
    where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return flags.Select(flag => flag).Aggregate(EnumHelper<T>.OrFunction);
}

private class EnumHelper<T>
    where T : struct,IConvertible
{
    static readonly Type typeofT = typeof(T);
    static readonly Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeofT);
    static readonly ParameterExpression[] parameters = 
    { 
        Expression.Parameter(typeofT), 
        Expression.Parameter(typeofT) 
    };

    static readonly Func<T, T, T> _orFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Or(
            Expression.Convert(parameters[0], underlyingType),
            Expression.Convert(parameters[1], underlyingType)
        ), typeofT), parameters).Compile();

    public static Func<T, T, T> OrFunction { get { return _orFunc; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library or look at the source code to see how you can do super fast generic bitwise operations on enum values. Here is the `SetFlags` method for example:

https://github.com/Singulink/Singulink.Enums/blob/d74f425f71b36189f0f1dbeb38b38d51ef7efa1d/Source/Singulink.Enums/EnumExtensions.cs#L152

It may look complex but the way it is written is super optimized and works properly for every underlying enum type. The JIT compiles that code into something that runs at almost the same speed as using bitwise operators directly. This is the quickest generic enum lib implementation around :)